# Remove /#/ from beginning of deep link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-address

I'm using the [jQuery Address plugin](http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/docs/) to do some dynamic address changes. So far I've got it to change the address bar to my page name but it adds a `/#/` at the beginning. I've had a look through the documentation but can't work out how to remove it.

My codes attached to a click event like so:

```
thisurl = "/portfolio";
$.address.path(thisurl);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to go with history.js to this .

Use `History.pushState("", "Title", newstate);` to change the addr bar and `History.Adapter.bind(window, 'statechange', function () {});` For the back and forward button events .

Comment: By using [jQuery Address](http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/),
You have a cross-browser solution, with fallback.

Comment: @Sujay same with history.js . https://github.com/balupton/History.js/ . Are you thinking of jquery.history ?

Comment: I thought you were looking for a routing solution. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Sujay I ended up coding my own version from scratch once I understood the history api a little more.

Comment: Thats gr8 @Frank . Please share it with us @ github or elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect somewhere you should use

```
thisurl = "/portfolio";
$(document).location = thisurl;
```

But if you only want to set a placeholder for your javascript app, I don't think you can do it without the `/#/`

Answer (score 0):

Chk out http://keithpitt.com/post/2826790132/jquery-address-ruby-on-rails-and-will-paginate!
By making use of the state changes, you can avoid hash-bangs.